# In windows programming, is there any way we can find out which module (Thread ID & DLL) is consuming CPU time?

Tags: c++, windows

I have made a sample application which will display all the process details which is running currently in my window smartphone device. such as NK.exe, filesys.exe etc.

I want to know how we can find out which module (Thread ID & DLL) is consuming CPU time? Most of the driver threads runs under device.exe / NK.exe and I am pretty sure that bulk of the CPU utilization will come from device.exe / NK.exe and Services.exe.

I want to know what are the threads running under **device.exe, NK.exe, Services.exe, filesys.exe** etc?

Comment: Yes. Our name is uncommon but a very good one.:D

Answer (score 1):

How to get CPU usage of processes and threads - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-get-CPU-usage-of-processes-and-threads

CPU usage - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-get-CPU-usage-of-processes-and-threads

GetThreadTimes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237%28VS.85%29.aspx

GetProcessTimes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223%28VS.85%29.aspx

GetSystemTime  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390%28VS.85%29.aspx

Processor Usage - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159461/Mobile-Processor-Usage